# How to Work Seamlessly Between Development, Staging, and Production Sites in wordpress

Tags: staging, development-strategy, production

am looking for a solution to stop coding like a cow boy on WordPress

I want to put a versioning system (git or bitbucket) With a Development, Staging, and Production site. Something like this

dev.site.com

staging.site.com

site.com

or

site.com/dev

site.com/staging

site.com

If possible is there a plugin or system to push from one version to an other.

Without having the database problem?

If you what to advise me on any program that I can use for that purpose on ubuntu.

Thanks for your help?

Comment: Have you read through [the many similar questions on this site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=staging) already?

Answer (score 1):

There's a good article at [WP Tavern](https://wptavern.com/git-and-wordpress-3-tips-to-do-it-better) that suggests some good methods. There is  also a plugin called WP Pusher.

With regard to using the different domains, like dev, staging, production, etc. you could [set up different remote repos](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes#Adding-Remote-Repositories) for dev, staging, production, etc. And then you can push to them individually depending on what stage of development you are in.

However, if you are using Ubuntu locally, I would set up a quick LAMP stack for your development environment. That way, you could see changes live without needing to push to your remote repo each time you make a change.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a Mac, check [Homebrew](https://echo.co/blog/os-x-1010-yosemite-local-development-environment-apache-php-and-mysql-homebrew) which creates an awesome local environment.

I'd recommend you define an ENV constant in the each environment's wp-config.

- For dev: define('ENV', 'dev' );
- For stage: define('ENV', 'stage' );
- For accept: define('ENV', 'accept' );
- For live: define('ENV', 'live' );

To make sure your non-live environments are not being indexed, you could use a simple function like this, which sets your blog to non-public, when the ENV is not set to live.

```
function set_robots() {
    $blog_public = get_option('blog_public');
    if ( ENV == 'live' ) {
        if ( $blog_public == 0 ) {
            update_option('blog_public', 1);
        }
    } else {
        if ( $blog_public == 1 ) {
            update_option('blog_public', 0);
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'set_robots' );
```

Comment: Homebrew just is a way to install a lot of other programs - how does it help with WordPress specifically? What programs should be installed using brew?

Comment: I might have read it a bit hastily... in terms of Wordpress homebrew doesn't do a lot...